# WPF menu and header images

Tags: wpf, menu

I need to have an image instead of text in my menu header. I have written a code but its not showing up the image.

Following is my xaml part for it.

```
<Menu Height="50" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsMainMenu="True">                
            <MenuItem Height="50" Width="50">
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Source="Images/pulsesi_icon_black.PNG"/>
                </MenuItem.Header>

            </MenuItem>

        </Menu>
```

Help me out of it, I don't need an Icon.

Comment: `Image.Source` path could be wrong. You sure, you have that image in the same project and image `BuildAction` set to `Resrouce`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Menuitem.Icon for image in header.

```
 <MenuItem >
   <MenuItem.Icon>
     <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="/Resources/Images/Key.jpg" />
   </MenuItem.Icon>
 </MenuItem>
```

Comment: have you got image or not?

Comment: nope, I dont see any image there, and i have image in my folder

Comment: where is your image folder? means image folder should be in your project, I am using above code in my project.